# В каком из вариантов индекс ускорит поиск?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть некоторая таблица:

```
create table Table1
(
  [a] int,
  [b] int,
  [c] int
)
```

И так же есть некоторый индекс Index1, в котором указаны поля `a`, `b`.

В каком из запросов индекс сработает?

1. `select * from Table1 where a = 1`
2. `select * from Table1 where b = 1`
3. `select * from Table1 where c = 1`
4. `select * from Table1 where a = 1 and b = 1`
5. `select * from Table1 where b = 1 and c = 1`

Я не разбираюсь в индексах, но мне кажется варианты 1, 2, 4 являются верными и индекс ускорит поиск, ведь там используются поля с индексом, однако постановка задачи такова, что вариант только один (в *каком* из запросов). Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вообще ответы 1 и 4. Это касается обычного B-Tree индекса конечно. Поиск по индексу возможен только если есть условие на первое поле из индекса. Конечно есть еще подводные камни вроде селективности индекса, но в вопросе нет данных. Как это привести к одному ответу не представляю

Comment: Какой **точно** индекс?

Comment: @Akina без понятия, не указан

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое!

Comment: Тогда только вариант 4. Ибо выражение индекса может быть как `(a,b)`, так и `(b,a)`, или даже `(c,b,a)` - все варианты соответствуют описанию "указаны поля a, b". Все остальные варианты - "при определённых условиях", тогда как 4-й - "всегда".

Comment: @Akina "Все варианты при определённых условиях" - это каких? Не могли бы описать? Или может подсказать, что загуглить конкретно...

Comment: *это каких? Не могли бы описать?* Второе предложение моего предыдущего комментария.

Comment: При такой постановке вопроса _"В каком из запросов индекс сработает?"_ ответ - it depends. Потому что `select *`, и если индекс, к примеру, по `(a, b)`, но селективность нехорошая, то оптимизатор его проигнорирует просто. Т.е. даже вариант 4 не гарантирован. Лучше было бы сформулировать _"В каком из запросов индекс **может** сработать?"_

Comment: ептить, прекратите вы сюда каике-то крайние ситуации приплетать. вполне ясная учебная проверочная задача. Mike вполне ответил в первом комменте, больше от этого вопроса не требуется.

Comment: @teran это наоборот хорошо для меня т.к я узнаю еще больше нового

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поля в индексе идут так как у условии(a, b), то запросы 1 и 4 ускорятся.
Если порядок (b, a), то 2 и 5 ускорятся.

---

Но это всё справедливо, если индекс кластеризованный, т.к. ты все поля из таблицы выбираешь. Если индекс некластеризованный, то не факт, что оптимизатор его будет использовать. В таких случаях нужно анализировать план запроса. Ну и разобраться в индексах - отличная идея.

Comment: а 4 не ускорится если `b,a`? и что-то про кластеризацию все поля не особо понятна ваша мысль

Comment: @teran неа. Представь содержание в конце книги, где сначала идут темы, а внутри(при необходимости) подтемы. Если попытаться искать по подтемам - ничего не выйдет. Нужно искать либо по теме, либо по теме+подтема. Картинка для понимания:
https://www.pdfindexgenerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Book-Index-Sample-1.jpg

Comment: давай уточняющий вопрос задам. Эквивалентны ли условия `a=1 and b=1` и `b=1 and a=1` ?